# SAQ A-EP - what do the initials stand for?

Tags: ecommerce, terminology

When it comes to delegating PCI compliance to payment service providers, there are two types of integrations: SAQ A and SAQ A-EP.

SAQ means Self-Assessment Questionnaire. But I can't figure out what "A" and "A-EP" mean. I've checked the [PCI glossary](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_Glossary_v3-2.pdf) and the [SAQ A-EP doc](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI-DSS-v3_2-SAQ-A_EP-rev1_1.pdf) but both seem to assume everyone knows what "A-EP" means.

Comment: Good question. I wasn't able to find an answer to this either.

Comment: Interesting that there's no answer on this after 5 years.